# How to move editingAccessoryView of custom UITableViewCell in edit mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

I have custom TableViewCell and want to use it in edit mode only. I like the delete accessory view in left side and reorder-control view in right side. But I want to move it a bit to the center of the cell. Can I do it?

I try something like this `[cell.editingAccessoryView setFrame:()]` but without any success.

Or the only option here is fully custom cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the view's frame isn't reset is likely because `self.editingAccessoryView` is `nil`, which is the case unless you set it with a view of your own.

Yes, you should try providing a custom editing view of your own and reset its `frame` property, but this may interfer with other existing views.

So your best bet is surely to make a full custom cell.