# How get rid of reorderControl while still using reorder?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

Not long ago [I asked about how to move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857334/how-to-move-editingaccessoryview-of-custom-uitableviewcell-in-edit-mode) reorderControl view close to the center of my custom cell, so this reorderControl break custom design. As I can't move this view and my cell always in editing mode - I just draw this reorderControl in right place of my cell background.   But now I have two reorderControls ) one from my background in right place and one from iOS. If I set return value of  `- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to NO, iOS reorderControl disappear but I can't reorder rows anymore.

How can I remove iOS reorderControl from screen and still be able to reorder my custom UITableViewCell?

ps cell.showsReorderControl=NO; is not working

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of a hack but the following does work

```
for(UIView* view in self.subviews)
    {
        if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"])
        {
            for(UIImageView* cellGrip in view.subviews)
            {
                if([cellGrip isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
                    [cellGrip setImage:nil];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I got it work in iOS7 is to add another method to find reorder control. Since the tableview structure has changed in iOS7 It was a little bit hard to track `UITableViewCellReorderControl`. It is now in `UITableViewCellScrollView`.

The solution is like below

```
- (void)changeReorderControl:(UITableViewCell *)cell subviewCell:(UIView *)subviewCell
{
    if([[[subviewCell class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {

        [subviewCell.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

        UIImageView *imageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hand"]];
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(subviewCell.frame.size.width/2 , subviewCell.frame.size.height/2);

        [subviewCell addSubview:imageView];
    }
}


- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    for(UIView* subviewCell in cell.subviews)
    {
            if([[[subviewCell class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellScrollView"])                {
                for(UIView* subSubviewCell in subviewCell.subviews) {
                    [self changeReorderControl:cell subviewCell:subSubviewCell];
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Hope you will get the idea.